# C++ count delay time?

Tags: c++

I want to make a scheduler, so I write looping with sleep every one usecond, but when I test the scheduler, the event is not called in the defined time.

I try to make it simple to verify the logic, but somehow the print is not really called in the defined time. I purpose to 1 second with `usecond(1)*1000000;`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  unsigned int delay = 0;
  for (;;) {
    usleep(1);
    delay++;
    if (delay >= 1000000) {
      cout << "TICK\n" << flush;
    }
  }
}
```

Result appears on 1 minute.

Comment: The above isn't a good way to write a scheduler.  A better way would be to calculate the time at which the next tick is supposed to occur, save that time into a variable, then subtract the current time from the calculated time.  The result of that subtraction tells you what value to pass in to usleep().  (Then after usleep() returns, you can again check the current time, and if it's greater than or equal to the calculated time, do the TICK thing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the man page

> The **usleep()** function suspends execution of the calling thread for (at least) usec microseconds. The sleep may be lengthened slightly by any system activity or by the time spent processing the call or by the granularity of system timers.

In other words, **usleep()** function suspends execution for greater than or equal to given time period with the precision available in the system.

I assume from your information the time granularity in your system is about 50 microseconds. That is the minimum suspending time regardless the parameter value.